# Will a Dyson product bought in Japan work in Australia?

Tags: electronic-items, tax-refunds

I will be going to Japan from Australia, and I am considering to buy a [Dyson 360](https://www.dyson.co.jp/dyson-vacuums/robot/360eye/360-eye-nickel-blue.aspx?subcat=robot) to bring and use in Australia.
**Q:** Would the [Dyson 360](https://www.dyson.co.jp/dyson-vacuums/robot/360eye/360-eye-nickel-blue.aspx?subcat=robot) bought in Japan work with the power supplier in the box or would I need a transformer for it to work in Australia?

Comment: @PeterM I will be _travelling_ to Japan, and during my _travels_ I will buy an electronic product. Will a product bought from an _overseas_ country (Japan) operate straight out of the box in Australia with an Japan >> Aus plug adaptor? I have had bad experience with a Dremel I bought from the USA due to the wattage difference :/

Comment: Just because an action is performed during traveling doesn't make it a travel related question.  What you are looking for is the specifications of the Japanese Dyson power plug/adapter.  Not something that we can tell you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about product functionality, not travel per se.

Comment: @PeterM fair point Sorry guys!

Comment: am i good to delete the question or does a moderator do it for me?

Comment: What is that thing even? A coffee maker? All the (presumbaly) explaining text in your link is in Japanese.

Comment: @3kstc You can delete the question yourself. There should be a link under the question on the left.

Comment: Yes, I think it will work. The Dyson 966613-01 is a "wall wart" type power supply, so there is a good chance it's "universal input" (the plugs vary). Of course the Japanese plug looks like the US plug and not the Aussie plug so you'd need a (cheap) plug adapter but not a voltage adapter. To be sure, just look at the label on the 966613-01 wall wart before you buy. If it says something like 90-250VAC then it will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should not expect this device to work "out of the box".  The voltage of wall outlets in Japan is 100 volts, while the voltage of wall outlets in Australia is 230 volts.  In effect, this means that a device built for Japanese homes will draw much more current than expected in Australia, which will cause it to put out much more heat than expected.  Unless you're trying to start a fire, this is a Bad Idea™.

Note that the USA runs on a similar voltage (120 V) to Japan.  So your plan will probably just replicate your experience with using a USA Dremel tool in Australia.

As an aside, the plugs are also of different shapes:  [Type A/B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#NEMA_1-15_ungrounded_(Type_A)) in Japan, [Type I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#Australasian_standard_AS/NZS_3112_(Type_I)) in Australia.  This means you couldn't even plug the thing into the wall in Australia without having some kind of jerry-rigged connection, which is another Bad Idea™.

Comment: Some sellers of this device in in the US on Amazon claim that they are sourcing UK versions of the device which support up to 240VAC.  So it is going to depend on the individual unit purchased in Japan.  Multi-voltage adapters are a thing for laptops and other electronics - but I have no clue what Dyson supplies.

Comment: @PeterM:  Fair point;  I've edited to clarify that my answer deals with a device built for use in Japan.

Comment: And from looking at the user manual, all this is a wall-wart that looks like it supplies DC to the charging dock.  So it's anyones guess what it supports.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thanks! that was all i want to clarify!